# Using loop to get value in different variable in a class C#

Tags: c#

I have a class with a different variable like this:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Example 
    {
       private double _var1;
       private double _var2;
       private double _var3;
       private double _var4;
       private double _var5;

       public double Var1
       {
          get { return _var1; }
          set { _var1 = value; }
       }

       public double Var2
       {
          get { return _var2; }
          set { _var2 = value; }
       }

       public double Var3
       {
          get { return _var3; }
          set { _var3 = value; }
       }

       public double Var4
       {
          get { return _var4; }
          set { _var4 = value; }
       }

       public double Var5
       {
          get { return _var5; }
          set { _var5 = value; }
       }

    }
 }
```

A method will using this class to be a model and assign a value to every variable in it.
How to get all the value in different variable inside this class? Thank you.

EDIT
I'm using Hassan code and the code look like this:

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo var in  typeof(Example).GetProperties())
    {
        if (var.Name.Contains("Var")) 
        {
             _dataTable.Rows.Add(_dateDailyBalance, var.GetValue(_justANormalModelOfExample, null));
        }
    }
```

but it returns all zero. the expected returns is some value. Why?

Comment: What exactly do you want to receive in the end? An array of `double`s from each `Var` property?

Comment: To loop through all the properties, I think you need to use reflection.

Comment: please provide the "method" that "will using this class" as well

Comment: that's why we use indexers, it's better to use indexer because your property looks same.

Comment: @user1008497 see my answer, easy way to do what you want, and let me know if you had any problem about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `System.Reflection` namespace:

For example setting `0.1` to each property.

```
 Example obj = new Example();
 Type type = obj.GetType();
 PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
 double d = 0.1;

 foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
 {           
      property.SetValue(obj, d, null);               
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hassan said, if you're dead set on using each as different variables, reflection would be the way to loop through the variables.

But if they're all doubles, why not array them? You could do this a number of ways...

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Example : IEnumerable<double>
    {
        private double vars = new double[5];

        protected double this[int ix]
        {
            get { return vars[ix]; }
            set { vars[ix] = value; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<double> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return vars;
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<double>)this).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to index an instance of the class like an array.

Answer (score 1):

because all of your properties are in same type, it is better to use indexer. here is an easy example of indexer, try to write it for your code. (i made this example because it is easy to understand)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass me = new MyClass();
        //you can use me[index] = value  for accessing the index of your indexer
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(me[i]);
        }
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    string[] name = { "Ali", "Reza", "Ahmad" };
    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return name[index]; }
        set { name[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

please let me know if you have any problem with understanding the code. and you need to change

```
string[]
```

to

```
double[]
```

for your code.

for more info see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx